# how to fire mapView:didSelectAnnotationView

Tags: objective-c, mkmapview

I'm new to iPhone development.  I've been reading several questions on how to make a google maps annotation callout window accept line breaks.  Every tutorial I've read requires me to fire the `mapView:didSelectAnnotationView` method.  But I have no idea how to trigger this.  things I've tried include

- putting the method in my MapViewController.m file which extends UIViewController
- putting the method in a MapView.m file which extends MKMapView, then have my Mapview element in my storyboard reference it as the class to use

There's so much about xcode, objective c, and iphone development that I don't understand, so i can't tell where my problem lies.

At the moment, my map does plot my desired marker on the desired location.  I just need to understand how to fire the  `mapView:didSelectAnnotationView` and `mapView:viewForAnnotation` functions before I can start customizing the call out box.

Does anyone have step by step instructions on how to trigger these functions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### A bit of background

A few things to note:

1. You don't call `mapView:didSelectAnnotationView`. The MKMapView calls that function on it's delegate. In other words, when you set up an MKMapView, you tell it: "hey, listen, anytimme you need to tell me what's happening on the map, go tell this guy, he'll handle them for you". That "guy" is the delegate object, and it needs to implement `mapView:didSelectAnnotationView` (that's also why its name "did select", ie, it already happened, as opposed to "select"). For a simple case, the delegate is often the `UIViewController` that owns the MKMapView, which is what I'll describe below.
2. That method will then get triggered when the user taps on one of your annotations. So that's a great spot to start customizing what should happen when they tap on an annotation view (updating a selection, for instance).
3. It's not, however, what you want if you want to customize what annotation to show, which is what it sounds like you're actually after. For that, there's a different method just a few paragraphs earlier [on the same man page](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapViewDelegate_Protocol/MKMapViewDelegate/MKMapViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/MKMapViewDelegate): `mapView:viewForAnnotation`. So substitute this method if you find that `mapView:didSelectAnnotationView` isn't what you were looking for.

### What you can do

If you got as far as a map with a marker, I'm guessing you have at least:
*   a view controller (extendeding from `UIViewController`, and
*   an `MKMapView` that you've added to the view for that view controller, say named `mapView`

The method you want to fire is defined as part of the `MKMapViewDelegate` protocol.
The easiest way to get this wired is to:

- make your UIViewController the delegate for you MKMapView

  - in code, say in your `viewDidLoad`, of your `MapViewController.m` you could do `mapview.delegate = self`, OR
  - in Interface Builder, you could drag the connection from the the MKMapView delegate property to the file's owner
- then, define a method on your UIViewController called `mapView:didSelectAnnotationView`, declaring it just like the protocol does, in your `MapViewController.m` file:

  ```
  - (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view {
      // whatever you need to do to your annotation and/or map
  }
  ```

Good luck!

Comment: +1 back to you for your honesty and the good answer. and yes I am your doppelganger (bahhhhh)

Answer (score 2):

`mapView:didSelectAnnotationView` is a delegate method of the map view, you can read about it here:
[MKMapViewDelegate Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/MapKit/Reference/MKMapViewDelegate_Protocol/MKMapViewDelegate/MKMapViewDelegate.html)

You don't need to call it, the map view will call it "by it self" and send it to every view/view controller that registered as it's delegate.

**What do you need to do**

Basically you need to add the MKMapViewDelegate on your .h file, what will look something like this:

```
@interface someViewController : UIViewController  <MKMapViewDelegate>
```

Then in the .m file, after you instantiate the map view you should add:

```
mapView.delegate = self;//were self refers to your controller
```

From this point and on your controller will be able to "receive messages" from the map view  which are the methods that you can see on the MKMapViewDelegate reference I linked to.

So to implement the mapView:didSelectAnnotationView you need to add in your .m file

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view{
     //if you did all the steps this methosd will be called when a user taps the annotation on the map. 
 }
```

**What is happening**

What happens in the background is:

1. The map view has a method (Apple codded) that handles the AnnotationView touch events.
2. When a touch event take place it sends a "message" to all of it's delegates saying "Hey a user **did Select Annotation View** on this map, Do with it what ever you need". 
   usually it looks like that:

   ```
    [self.delegate mapView:someMapView didSelectAnnotationView:someAnnotationView];
   ```
3. Then every view/controller that assigned itself as a delegate and implemented the method will cal this method.

Good luck

Comment: Good god are you me in some parallel universe? Swear I saw the new answer banner as I reached to click "post". Even the "good luck" at the end, sheesh. I'd be a hypocrite not to upvote!

Comment: Thanks,i used both your answer and ckhan to get things wokring.

Answer (score 0):

```
Place *place = [[Place alloc] init];
PlaceMark *placeMark = [[PlaceMark alloc] initWithPlace:place];
[self.mapView selectAnnotation:placeMark animated:YES];
```

Comment: Good posts explain the answer provided. Here you've just written code with no explanation