# How would I call this method from the viewDidLoad method?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, viewdidload

How would I call this method from the `viewDidLoad` method?

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapview didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view {
       // code
  }
```

I'm stuck on the syntax: `[self mapview:.....];`

Comment: how about [self mapView:nil didSelectAnnotationView:nil];

Comment: check this:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10492401/how-to-fire-mapviewdidselectannotationview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't - that's a call back you get from an [`MKMapView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html) when a user touches an [`MKAnnotationView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/MapKit/Reference/MKAnnotation_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/MKAnnotation). If you want to automatically select your annotation when your `MKMapView` is loaded, use its [`selectAnnotation:animated`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/MKMapView/selectAnnotation%3aanimated%3a) method.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
   MKMapView *mapView = // whatever
   MKAnnotation *annotation = // whatever
   [mapView selectAnnotation:annotation animated:YES]; // could be no, in viewDidLoad it won't necessarily be visible
}
```

When you call `selectAnnotation:animated:`, your annotation will pop up, then, if the user touches it, your `mapView:didSelectAnnotation:` will be called. As a rule, you will never call the methods in [`MKMapViewDelegate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/MapKit/Reference/MKMapViewDelegate_Protocol/MKMapViewDelegate/MKMapViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008204) (or any *Delegate for that matter). The system will call them for you at the appropriate time.

P.S. [`viewDidLoad`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewDidLoad) doesn't take an argument.

Answer (score 1):

You don't call `mapView:didSelectAnnotationView`. The `MKMapView` calls that function on it's delegate. Check this : [how to fire mapView:didSelectAnnotationView ?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10492565/1603072)

```
 [self.delegate mapView:someMapView didSelectAnnotationView:someAnnotationView];
```

Comment: He might want to select an default annotation on the map. In which case this would be a valid way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Paste this into xcode:

```
[self mapView:<#MKMapView instance#> didSelectAnnotationView:<#MKAnnotationView instance#>];
```

You will need to pass the references to the `mapView` and the `annotationView` for this to work.